# Getting null values from Model while there are records

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch

This is where i am doing the Query i am getting null values on using dynamic query

```
            var responsedata = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Acquirer>(s => s
                           .Query(q => q.ConstantScore(cs => cs.Filter(
                            f =>
                            f.Term("MERCHANTNO.keyword", MerchantNo)
                                 )))
                );
```

This is my model

```
    public class Acquirer
    {
        public string MERCHANTNO { get; set; }
    }
```

This is where index mapping is done

```
            client.Map<Acquirer>(m =>
            {
                var putMappingDescriptor = m.Index(Indices.Index("acquiringdata")).AutoMap();
                return putMappingDescriptor;
            });
```

I am getting the exact number of records but i am getting the null values

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Error can be Resolved by using this
[PropertyName("MERCHANTNO")]